# Will any monitor work with Windows 8?

Tags: display, windows-8, requirements

I am almost ready to switch to Windows 8, but I have one last concern: Will any monitor work with Windows 8? I am using a Dynex TV as my monitor, and it worked fine with Windows 7. Will it work with Windows 8? What are the requirements of a monitor for Windows 8?

Comment: It should work but just cross check with the manufacturer once. You can also see this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home?Length=0

Comment: This doesn't seem like a dupe to me. The other question is specifically about the Snap feature, whereas this discusses any and all requirements Windows 8 might have with regards to the display. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 8 has two resolution requirements:

- You need at least 768 *vertical* pixels to be able to use Metro apps at all. This means a resolution of 1024×768 or greater. Smaller resolutions will only be able to run legacy desktop applications.
- You need at least 1366 *horizontal* pixels to be able to use Metro Snap (displaying two Metro apps on the screen at the same time). This means a resolution of 1366×768 or greater<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Greater means more pixels in both dimensions. For instance, 1280×1024 is technically a larger resolution than 1366×768 based on sheer pixel count (1.3 megapixels vs. 1.0), but it's not wide enough to allow for Metro Snap.

Comment: A friend of mine, who has the same monitor, just installed Win8. He said that the monitor is displaying the screen to widely... Thanks though.

Comment: Just want to add, you should also be able to connect the monitor with the interfaces your computer provides. Otherwise you'll need a conversion adapter or in the worst case another graphics card.